# Bootstrap datepicker Keyboard navigation : select date when "tabbing out"

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using [Boostrap Datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in an app and my users are requesting a change for its [Keyboard navigation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html).

We'd like the date to be set when pressing [tab] (moving to next input) rather than having to press [enter] before leaving to the next input.

Alternatively, up/down/left/right arrow could directly change the date when moving instead of focusing a date. But I'd prefer a solution that only change date when leaving the input.

Comment: Dont get your problem. Actually if you click a date and focus out with tab he keeps the date you selected.

Comment: User doesnt' to click. they use the form with keyboard only. 1. Tab to move to the date field 2. arrows to change date 3. enter to select the date 4. tab to move to the next field ... They like to drop step 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box solution to this. 
You have to code this functionally yourself. Add a key-listener Event to the datepicker and check if "tab" (keycode = 9) is pressed. If tab is pressed, [set the datepicker with the new value](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#update)

Sorry that I can't give you a working example but there is no simple, short solution to it.

Comment: The question is then : how to know the focused date ?

Comment: Unfortunately there seems no way to get it via the api from the datepicker itself, but you can find it out with js: The focused day in the datepicker-overlay has the focus class, it's easy to select it with jquery $(".datepicker .focused"), the month and year are in the table header.

Comment: Eventually, I ended up with a listener that would store the focused date on keyboard navigation (up, down, left, right)  and set the datepicker date when tabbing out.
See code on https://gist.github.com/tbuyle/7b891ee898fc656b002c9db92c741e26